# Align the text of a button to the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am facing a problem.
I want to align the text of a button to the bottom with a padding of 20dp.
However, the text sticks at the bottom of my button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/CatButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_1_selected"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:text="test"/>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is ur problem is text not shown at bottom ?

Comment: Use `bottom|center` instead of `bottom|center_horizontal`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change **layout_gravity = "bottom"**, your button align bottom; but if you change **gravity = "bottom"**, your button's text align bottom. You should do that:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/catButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:text="test"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"/>
```

Comment: android:gravity="center|bottom" works just fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`.

If you want its text shows in center, you should set `android:gravity="center"`.

--Edit--

It was a mistake. I misunderstood.

You should set `android:gravity="center|bottom"`.

Comment: if set android:gravity="center" then text not going to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/CatButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can implement it with the help of `gravity` attribute.

```
android:gravity="start|bottom"
```

Eg:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:text="submit"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"/>
```